# VS 2019 : Build Docker image throw Exception at Run dotnet restore

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I've 4 projects (asp.net core 3.0) in a solution (Visual studio 2019). I've add a dockerFile for each projects via (>Add Docker Support), now I'm trying to build the docker Image but each time an error is thrown at the step run dotnet restore :  : *NuGet.targets(123,5): error : Unable to load the service index for source https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json, NuGet.targets(123,5): error :   No such host is known* .

I've seen many solutions on internet and I tried everything but nothing worked :

- I've already install/uninstall docker
- I've turn off proxy settings
- I don't have an environment variable called http_proxy
- I'm able to open the link  https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json in the browser
- I've add proxy settings in nuget.config (I've also tried deleting it and let vs recreate it)

I'm kinda stuck here, If anyone has an idea, I'm open to everything !

If you need more infos about what I've tried or else, let me know !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after some deeper digging, I found this solution : https://improveandrepeat.com/2019/09/how-to-fix-network-errors-with-docker-and-windows-containers/ . It fixed my problem !